# Java Reading a file using readAllLines and saving it into a list

Tags: java, file, filepath

For my studies I have to write a huge program with some other folks and right now I'm trying to read a specific file and save it's content into a list. After this we need to access the list, move it's content around, change stuff, compare it and so on.

Here's what I tried so far, but it gives me the error:

> The method readAllLines(Path, Charset) in the type file is not applicable for the arguments(Path).

```
public static Collection<Order> readFromFile(String filePath) throws IOException {
    Map<String, Order> orderMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filePath));
```

Thing is, we never really did Java before and I'm real noobish and don't even know what I'm doing there.

Comment: I recommend reading the documentation of the classes to understand how you can use the methods. This will help you greatly. Here is the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)). And the thing is your missing a parameter Charset in your method call, that is what the error is saying.

Comment: I wholeheartedly recommend you to step back for a second. You are saying that you will have to write a **huge** program; on the other hand, you are saying "I don't know what I am doing". That is simply spoken not a good position to start with. There are only two reasonable options now: a) you forget about your project or b) you bite the bullet and start learning. What I mean is: stackoverflow can help you with specific problems; but we can't teach you. You have to sit down, and start learning the very basics; and then go forward.

Comment: Use the Google first and then come back when you're really stuck and have some working code for us to reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception you're receiving is because that method you're calling takes two parameters, not one. You're calling it with a path, but the method is expecting a `Path` parameter and a `Charset` ([see this for more info](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/java.nio.file/Files/Java_Files_readAllLines_Path_path_Charset_cs_.htm)). Remember, Google is your best friend when it comes to exceptions like these! Good luck with your project.